# Matlab plotting 4 vecotrs

Tags: matlab, plot

**Entire Code**

```
clear;clc
d1= 0.34;
d2= 0.15;
d3=0.27;
deltat = 1; 
W = 1000.0; 
X = 0.0; 
Y = 0.0;
Z=0.00; 
for t = 1:30
W(t+1) = W(t) - deltat*d1*W(t); 
X(t+1) = X(t) - deltat*d2*X(t); 
X(t+1) = X(t+1) + deltat*d1*W(t); 
Y(t+1) = Y(t)- deltat*d3*Y(t); 
Y(t+1) = Y(t+1) + deltat*d2*X(t); 
Z(t+1)=Z(t);
Z(t+1)=Z(t+1) + deltat*d3*Y(t);
end
figure(1)
plot(W(t),X(t),Y(t),Z(t))
title('Radioactive Decay','FontSize',14)
legend('W','X','Y','Z');
xlabel('Time (days)');
ylabel('Kilograms');
W(30)
X(30)
Y(30)
Z(30)
```

**Part I am having trouble with**

```
plot(W(t),X(t),Y(t),Z(t))
```

**Issue**

I was trying to plot the W, X, Y and Z graphs together on one plot to show the change over the 30 days period I have assigned, however it seems like the formatting I put is wrong because the resultant plot ends up being empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because the plot-function is only for two-dimensional line plots. Documentation: https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html

The way you have written it is plotting W(t) on one axis, X(t) on another axis and so forth summing up to four dimensions.

Use

```
plot(W); hold on;
plot(X); hold on;
plot(Y); hold on;
plot(Z);
```

Comment: Thanks! the concept of this worked. I just had to remove the (t) and capitalize the letters to get the right graph.

Comment: The answers is now edited to the more correct solution.